# Question regarding a linear transformation on the space of real polynomials of degree $\leq n$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be the linear space of all real polynomials $p(x)$ of degree $\leq n$. If $p\in V$, $q=T(p)$ means that $q(x)=p(x+1)$ for all real $x$.

I was able to show the $T$ is a linear transformation. However, I am having some difficulties determining $\ker(T)$ , the range, the nullity and rank.

For the rank, I think that it is $n$.

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not very complicated. Just note that $T$ has an inverse, given by $S(q) = p$, where $p(x) = q(x-1)$. This means that $T$ is injective, and everything else should follow readily.

Comment: I think you meant bijective.

Comment: Since T is injective, then Ker(T)={0} right?

Comment: @user43418, yes, and then, as julien as noted, also surjective etc.

Comment: @user43418 Yes of course. But we directly have $TS=ST=Id$.

Comment: @julien, injective and surjective, sure, but I started with injective to get the kernel right first.

Comment: So, since Ker(T)={0}, the nullity i.e. dim(Ker(T))={0} and therefore the rank ie dim(Im(T))=dim(V)=n

Comment: @user43418 Yes, you can use the rank-nullity theorem here if you want. But note that the result is still true with the space of all polynomials, without restrictions on the degree. And this is because $ST=TS=Id$.

Comment: What is the range of this application please?

Comment: @user43418 Approach 1: since $TS=Id$, the range is the whole space $V$. Approach 2: since $\dim (Im T)=n=\dim V$, the range is the whole space $V$.